# how to get related mysql php records?

Tags: php, mysql, datagrid

I have mysql table  'files'. which contains following order.
1. id 2.filename 3.keywords

When displaying one file i want to show the related files from same database table order by most matched keywords.

should it be like

```
 $keywords = $db->getkeywords('5');

 //getting related files

 $sql = "select * from 'file's where 'keywords' like '$keywords'";
```

????

Comment: you need to add more infos, what getkeywords returns?

Comment: getkeywords returns the keywords of id 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$keywords = join(',' $db->getkeywords('5')); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE keywords IN ($keywords)";
```